# Android Studio shuts down when adding android:text attribute to any element in any xml layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm encountering a weird issue that started over night. If I open any xml layout file with the line
android:text="whatever" in an element, Android Studio immediately shuts down with no errors displayed.
Android Studio works perfectly fine for any other tasks. I've been going through similar questions and trying solutions with no success, until manually typing I noticed THIS attribute is causing the crash.

For example,

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailtextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

works perfectly.
But when the line `android:text="TextView"` is added even manually the programs shuts down.
The same happens with buttons.

I can even run the app but I can't edit the xml from Android Studio.
Why might this be?

Comment: are you sure added android:text="whatever" this line android studio shuts down pls give me any more information for this question.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Not sure of how to be more explicit. Either if I manually write the line or load the android:text attribute in Declared Attributes, the moment I finish doing so Android Studio shuts down immediately.